# Someone knows how to union two or more materialized views in sql?

Tags: sql, select, union, sql-view, materialized-views

```
select * 
from 
    (materialized_v1
     union all
     materialized_v2);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to `select`, then `union`. There is nothing specific about materialized view here:

```
select * from materialized_v1 
union all 
select * from materialized_v2;
```

For this to work both views to have the same number of columns, with the same datatypes. It is far better to enumerate the columns in the `select` clauses, which gives you a chance to adjust the columns and datatypes if needed:

```
select col1, col2, col3 from materialized_v1 
union all 
select col4, col4, col5 from materialized_v2;
```

Comment: Thanks , can i create a materialized view using others materialized views ?